# how to add element in nested array of objects of array in mongodb

Tags: arrays, database, mongodb, mongoose, nested

This image contains [my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBekf.png) , 
I am using mongodb as database and mongoose for connection

I want to push elements in topics array and in subTopics array

Comment: Please attach the document as a snippet and provide the sample input data and expected output. Thanks.

Comment: I have a model named Classroom which will contain the data in the format shown in image , now I want to update this data by adding more topics and subtopics

Comment: if you can, give the data as JSON text and the expected output as JSON text, so we can copy them, write a query and test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  arrayFilters for the task , example:

This will push new element={test:1} in the topics array with element with sessionName:'Java':

```
 db.c.update( { name: "class 1" } , { $push: { 'sessions.$[x].topics':{test:1 } } } , { arrayFilters : [{ 'x.sessionName':'Java' }] }  )
```

This will push element=1 in the subTopics array with _id:1 from sessions with sessionName='Java':

```
 db.c.update( { name: "class 1" } , { $push: { 'sessions.$[x].topics.$[y].subTopic':1 } } , { arrayFilters : [{ 'x.sessionName':'Java' },{'y._id':1}] }  )
```

Comment: and for deleting  them what should I do

Comment: For delete you can use $pull or $unset the same way